# Are the two uses of “Frau” in “Frau Hauptfrau” redundant?

Tags: meaning, phrase

A friend will sometimes reply to my texts in German. His reply recently to a question was “Jawohl, Frau Hauptfrau.”  The use of *Frau Hauptfrau* appears redundant.  When I use lower case on Frau and Hauptfrau the sentence takes on a whole different translation.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean saying lower case? You cannot write "frau hauptfrau", it's ungrammatical.

Comment: People would also say "Herr Hauptmann", so no, it is not redundant. But it is unclear why you think making something lower case would be a good idea.

Comment: When I used a German to English translation as originally written, the translation is "Yes, Madame Hauptfrau" as if my last name is Hauptfrau.  When I use Frau hauptfrau, translation is "yes, my wife".  When I use frau Hauptfrau, translation is "wife, head woman." It seems redundant to use "Frau" and "Hauptfrau" together as they both refer to someone of the female gender.

Comment: @Susan: "the translation is" - according to who? IMHO, the other translations beside "Yes, Madame Hauptfrau" are bogus.

Comment: I use Google translate.  I use this when I translate the words/phrases my friend uses.  I have never had any reason for pause or question previously, but this most recent phrase "Jawohl, Frau Hauptfrau" didn't make sense.  I understand Frau is used as a noun, but the my last name is not Hauptfrau.  The translation of Hauptfrau, uppercase "H" appears to be head woman or chief woman.  Using Frau Hauptfrau is "wife, head woman." My friend and I are not of a romantic nature.  I do not want to replay in such a way that would embarrass or confuse either one of us.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: This is Google Translate being unpredictable or trying to guess the meaning when context is lacking. *Hauptfrau* can be translated as *main wife* in polygynic contexts but that makes little to no sense here to real humans.

Comment: Is your friend a native speaker or at least reasonably competent in German? If so, which I think likely, I think this is a parody of _Jahwohl, Herr Haptmann_ (and thus a joke), if not they have probably made a mistake. It is to be expected that Google translate is sensitive to case, since German is; the lower case probably reduces its confidence in a given interpretation.

Comment: If he is a friend, why do you not ask him to explain? Since it is probably a joke, he ought to be glad to do so.

Comment: Just to be clear: In the Bundeswehr, it's "Frau Hauptmann", "Frau Bootsmann", "Frau Stabsapotheker", etc.

Comment: @phresnel But not everybody knows that.

Comment: @glglgl: Yes, that's why I added the comment.

Comment: This is obviously a playful / creative use of language. You should add more context.

Comment: Think of "Mr. Sandman". Neither "Mr." nor "-man" are redundant.

Comment: I suppose your friend felt that you bossed, even commanded him around and wanted to indicate that he will follow your wishes, albeit with an ironic twist in order to communicate playfully that he felt you were bossy. The irony is conveyed through the word play: There is no "Hauptfrau", like there is no "Majorette" in English speaking armies. Outside the military this response style (even without the word play) to a wish would always be ironic; I suspect that it could have that undertone even in today's army, if uttered with emphasis.

Comment: In response to Mr. Geiselmann regarding context.  I had attended the funeral of my friend's mother on the day previous to this texting exchange.  He had texted to ask if I had arrived home safely (i flew to the funeral).  I asked if his sister was still in town.  His response was "Jawohl, Frau Hauptfrau".  PJTraill is correct in suggested I just ask directly.  Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 40):

> **Q:** *Are the two uses of “Frau” in “Frau Hauptfrau” redundant?*

No. It's not redundant:

- *[Frau](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Frau)* is a form of address: like madam or mister, in this case the standard German female form of address.
- *[Hauptfrau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptfrau)* is a form of title: probably a word play on function, either alluding to (mock/pseudo) [polygamous](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zweitfrau) [relationship](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Hauptfrau), or derived from an analogon to *[Hauptmann](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Landeshauptfrau),* (with a pseudo feminist or mock-progressive undertone) although that specific word is currently [not really en vogue](http://www.general-anzeiger-bonn.de/news/panorama/Die-Vorst%C3%A4ndin-ist-nicht-aufzuhalten-article1031861.html) for that scenario. It doesn't need to be a military context, but is in the case of OP just indicating something like "this female is authorised to give orders".

---

As Rudy Velthuis commented:

> Think of "Mr. Sandman". Neither "Mr." nor "-man" are redundant.

To which I'd like to expand, suppose the name of a male is *Liebherr*:

> Lieber Herr Liebherr,  (Dear Mr Liebherr)

Looks awfully redundant, but no part can be left out without changing the meaning quite significantly.

And since "Jawohl" attracts so much attention here, another example illustrating a strictly non-military, but hierarchical context:

> Jawohl, Herr Unterkammerherr. (Yes sir, Mr under chamberlain.)

---

The corresponding *[Herr](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herr) [Hauptmann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptmann)* is equally not redundant, despite *Herr* and *-mann* also both indicating *male*.
As redundancy implies that one part might be superfluous: leaving out the second part of *Hauptfrau* makes no sense. Leaving out the first Frau, the honorific  address, changes the meaning.

---

In response to comments: *"Jawohl, Herr Hauptmann/Frau Hauptfrau!"* is not such much (or even strongly?) indicative of a real military context, but very probably just *alluding* to one –– or a similar situation; more often jokingly playful than really Prussian militaristic tone.

<sub>Or as @schmuddi has put it:</sub>

> <sub>It's not just the jawohl that suggests the military context but the whole construction Jawohl, Herr [Rang], where [Rang] refers to the position in a strict hierarchy, and no last name follows. Granted, something like Jawohl, Herr Professor might be used in a non-military context, but it appears horribly old-fashioned to me, especially if contrasted with a much more appropriate Jawohl, Herr Professor Schmuddi which you'd still encounter in contemporary use. Note: This may be different in Austrian and Swiss German.</sub>

---

<sub>But "military context" is strictly *not* what the situation in question describes: "a friend writing *occasionally* to a female with that form of address". As emphasised elsewhere on this page, "Hauptfrau" *is not the correct form of address in the German army anyway, and this is not alternated with the *correct form*, to make the joke.</sub>

<sub>In any case: the meaning and context of "Hauptfrau" or "Jawohl" is interesting in it self, but hardly applicable to this question and almost totally irrelevant to the question of whether this is redundant or not.</sub>

Comment: In my opinion, "Jawohl" is strongly indicating military context.

Comment: "Jawohl" does not indicate military context, and definitely not "strongly" - waiters or hotel person staff and sometimes even sales people also would use this.

Comment: It's not just the *jawohl* that suggests the military context but the whole construction *Jawohl, Herr [Rang]*, where *[Rang]* refers to the position in a strict hierarchy, and no last name follows. Granted, something like *Jawohl, Herr Professor* might be used in a non-military context, but it appears horribly old-fashioned to me, especially if contrasted with a much more appropriate *Jawohl, Herr Professor Schmuddi* which you'd still encounter in contemporary use. **Note**: This may be different in Austrian and Swiss German.

Comment: Jawohl, Herr Doktor, unter diesen Umständen werde ich meine Tabletten rechtzeitig einnehmen  `:-)`

Comment: A simple example in English that isn't *quite* comparable would be: "Hello, Mr Chairman". You can't remove the "man" because then you're saying "Hello Mr Chair" which is rather a different greeting.

Comment: I think outside of the military context, an unironic "Jawohl" is only used out of habit by (former) soldiers. Usually it's ironically to mock someone for beeing bossy.

Comment: I'd concur that it suggests military context. Pretty sure people in everyday life only yell "Jawohl" (optionally with straightening up and knocking heels together for extra dramatic effect) to mock someone of his Spiess-like tone.

Answer (score 28):

"Hauptfrau" seems to be a feminized version of "Hauptmann", a rank in the German army equivalent to a Captain in the US Army. However, the term "Hauptfrau" is incorrect. Military ranks do not get gendered. So a woman holding the rank of Hauptmann in the German army is addressed with "Frau Hauptmann".

"Jawohl" is the preferred way to affirm an order in the German army.

So the military correct way to respond to an order from a female Hauptmann and/or to mock a woman who is acting like one would be "Jawohl, Frau Hauptmann". Next time your friend writes this, I recommend to establish your military authority by responding with: "Es heißt 'Jawohl Frau Haupt**mann**', Gefreiter [surname]! Wegtreten!".

(*Gefreiter* = lowest rank in the German army, *Wegtreten* = order to leave and execute the orders the soldier just received)

Source: I used to be a soldier in the German army and got scolded for making this mistake once.

Comment: Actually, Gefreiter is only the second lowest rank.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I knew that sooner or later someone would claim that. But I am not going to debate you because it would just lead to a boring off-topic discussion about semantics.

Comment: `Military ranks do not get gendered.`: This might change soon. In the UK it's already happening. At least, if we can trust the Daily Mail and other news media with (even) lower reputation.  (https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-6500361/Army-officers-told-refer-combat-soldiers-infanteers.html)

Answer (score 14):

The word "Hauptfrau" can have different meanings.

Normally when I hear the word "Hauptfrau" I would translate it as "first wife" or "head wife". In some cultures (Germany not included), a man can have multiple wives, with the "Hauptfrau" being the first or most important wife.

In this context, however, I would interpret it as the female form of "Hauptmann", which translates to "captain" in the military sense.

So as "Jawohl, Herr Hauptmann." translates to "Yes, captain." or "Yes, sir." I would say that "Jawohl, Frau Hauptfrau." translates to "Yes, captain." or "Yes, ma'am."

I do think it sounds a bit funny because of the word "Frau" appearing twice, <strike>but it is still correct</strike>.

**Edit:**

A quick google search reveals that there is no official female form of "Hauptmann":

[Dienstgrade in der Bundeswehr – Keine "Hauptfrau" als Kompaniechefin, n-tv, 02. Juli 2001:](https://www.n-tv.de/politik/Keine-Hauptfrau-als-Kompaniechefin-article139755.html)

> Im täglichen Sprachgebrauch wird lediglich der übliche Dienstgrad mit der weiblichen Anrede versehen. So wird die "Frau Hauptmann" ebenso normal sein wie die "Frau Bootsmann", die es bei den Sanitäterinnen schon seit 25 Jahren gibt.

So a woman would be called "Frau Hauptmann" if she was the captain of a company.

Anyway, I still think that your friend wanted to call you "captain" and tried to be politically correct by using what he thought was the female form of the word.

Comment: Also, Gabriele Burgstaller preferred to be called _Frau Landeshauptfrau_ when she was Landeshauptmann (Councillor) of state Salzburg. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabi_Burgstaller)

Answer (score 7):

I believe this to be a variant of the somewhat more common ‘Jawohl, Herr Hauptmann!’ It is a phrase associated with accepting the order of your superior in the military. (As I have never been in the military, I cannot tell you how high up a *Hauptmann* is and whether it would be considered the correct reply or not. I do note that for non-soldiers it is immediately recognisable as such.)

In this male form, *Herr* is the same title that would be added before one’s name in sufficiently formal contexts: Herr Müller, Herr Schneider. Using *Herr* together with a function is possible (sometimes preferable) if one doesn’t know the person’s surname or if there is precedence in protocol: *Herr Schaffner, Herr Bundeskanzler, Herr Präsident.* For women, this *Herr* becomes *Frau* in all contexts: *Frau Müller, Frau Schaffnerin, Frau Bundeskanzlerin.*

*Hauptmann* is one of the German job descriptions ending in *-mann* which corresponds to the English ending *-man.* Another example is *Kaufmann*, in English this compares e.g. to *policeman, congressman.* Where the person performing this job is not male but female, it is common to replace the final *-mann* with *-frau* in German as you would replace *-man* with *-woman* in English: *Kaufmann* becomes *Kauffrau* and *congressman* becomes *congresswoman.* (As the other answer notes, military grades may follow different rules.)

In the combination of both, we have the title (which happens to be *Frau)* and the job (which happens to end in *Frau)* and we put the two together to give:

> Frau Hauptfrau

It does seem a little comical even to German speakers but it is undoubtedly grammatically correct.

Comment: I would argue that _Hauptmännin_ is also grammatically correct and semantically preferred, although it would have referred to the wife of an officer in the 19th century. Military ranks are rarely derived into a feminine form, and for many of them it feels strange (_Majorin, Gefreite_), uncertain (_Oberste_?, _Generalin/Generälin_) or even wrong (*_Leutnantin_).

Comment: @Crissov I hope I didn’t imply semantic preference anywhere, only grammatical correctness. On the other ranks: I would argue that *Oberste* would be the female form of *Oberster* so I would maybe prefer *Oberstin.* On the other hand, the French look of *Leutnant* leads me to suggest *Leutnante* as a female form – but I consider this academic speculation for the most part as the Bundeswehr will state what it considers correct when it needs to.